# Connect multiple drupal 8 instances with same database

Tags: php, drupal-8

I am facing a strange issue with drupal 8. We have setup a git repo for drupal 8 project, shared withing 4 developers. Each developer is pointing to common cenralized database. Everything works fine except the css assets not loading at all.

The css keeps going on and off and only one instance is works correcly.

We have created common virtual environment for development say dev.drupal8.loc

Let me know if anyone faced such issue before and resolution to such problem.

Thanks.

Comment: This question might be a better fit at [drupal.se].

Comment: Thanks Ivar.. will try there

Comment: is the Site URL same for everyone ? just a guess!

Comment: Yes, codebase is cloned seperately, but database is shared, and all have same virtual host dev.drupal8.loc

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?